# Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector, range, subscript

I'm getting the vector subscript out of range error. I've had it before, but it prints 'before' but it doesn't print 'after' so I'm confused at to why one of these lines would be causing it.

```
cout << "before" << endl;
vector<vector<char>> animals;
vector<vector<char>> food;
vector<char> other;
int lastline = 0;
for(int i=1;i<=(c);i++){
cout << "after" << endl;
```

Comment: Can you edit to fix your open-ended for loop, please?

Comment: It doesn't print 'after'

Comment: It will be difficult to find help if you don't include the line where `c` is defined.

Comment: Why does c matter?... It's just an integer.

Comment: @Pig Head : Is your code working? No? That's why it matters.

Comment: Wait, sorry, I made a very silly mistake - the loop never runs and it's easy to identify the problem after.

Comment: In future try to post all the relevant code, from what you have posted here we wouldn't be able to actually help you out with the problem as there is not enough info here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `c` is the count of elements in any vector, then the mistake is simply that in a vector with `N` items the item indexes are `0...[N-1]` and not `1...N`.

Therefore, make this correction:

```
for(int i=0; i < (c); i++) {
```

By the way, in C-like languages the archetype of a `for` loop that iterates `N` times is, not coincidentally:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
```

Stick with this unless you have a very very good reason to make an exception, and you get to avoid this type of bug "for free".

Comment: It never reaches the loop, it doesn't print 'after'.

Comment: Just to append to Jons answer, A size() method exists to get the count of elements in the vector. It's generally better style to make use of this method call (if you aren't already)

Comment: vector< vector<char> > animals; Should be written like this. Mind the space

Comment: That's not what the loop does. The error is before the loop.

Comment: I used this and found the problem even though this is not the solution, thanks :)