# Vector Subscript out of range when decrementing from 100 to 0

Tags: c++, class, c++11, operator-overloading, stdvector

I debugged this error, and I cannot understand the reason as to why this vector subscript is going out of range. I have also looked at this link but it was to no avail: 
[Vector subscript out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920839/vector-subscript-out-of-range)

I have a class called `board` with a private data member `vector<int> m_Board_board`. In the `board` constructor, I am initializing this variable from `1` to `100` and using the `friend operator <<` function to print from last to the end like so:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::ostream;

class Board
{
private:
   vector<int> m_Board_board;
public:
   Board()
   {
      for (int i = 1; i < 101; ++i)  {
         m_Board_board.push_back(i);
      }
   }

   friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Board board)
   {
      for (int i = 100; i > 0; --i) {
         os << board.m_Board_board[i] << '\n';
      }
      return os;
   }
};

#endif // !BOARD_H
```

In my `main` function, I am printing out the board.

```
#include "Board.h"    
using std::cout;

int main()
{
   Board board;
   cout << board;
   system("pause");
}
```

This creates the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWVQF.png

Now the bizarre thing is if I change my `operator <<` function to print from start to the end, it works as expected!

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::ostream;

class Board
{
private:
   vector<int> m_Board_board;

public:
   Board() 
   {
      for (int i = 1; i < 101; ++i) {
         m_Board_board.push_back(i);
      }
   }

   friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Board board)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
         os << board.m_Board_board[i] << '\n';
      }
      return os;
   }
};
#endif // !BOARD_H
```

They are both doing the same thing, but one is throwing *vector subscription out of range error*, while the other works fine. Now before I get comments saying that I must use iterators, I tried them with iterators and the same thing happened, which led me to try using the normal integer loops to figure out if the problem was with using the iterators or not. However, it is not the iterators it is something weird!

However, in the first case when I am iterating from `99` to `0`, it works perfectly but it does not print the first element (obviously!).

So, why is it going out of range when I am starting to decrement from `100` down to `0`?

Comment: They are **not** doing the same thing. One iterates from 0 to 99, the other from 100 downto 1.

Comment: You could easily debug this yourself by simply printing the `size()` of the vector after each `for` loop.  Any index above `size() - 1` is out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not doing the same!

Your `m_Board_board` has 100 elements in it, meaning the indexing start from `0, 1, 2,..., 99` and in the first code, in the loop

```
for (int i = 100; i > 0; --i) {
```

you are starting the index `100`. This is trying to accessing the non-existing element in the vector vis `std::vector::operator[]`, which is [access out of bounds undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Access_out_of_bounds). That is anything could happen. In your case, you had a program crash.

You should have started from `99` instead to have the defined behaviour

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Board const& board) /* noexcept */
//                                              ^^^^^^^--> also pass the object by const-ref
{
   for (int i = 99; i >= 0; --i) {
      os << board.m_Board_board[i] << '\n';
   }
   return os;
}
```

---

or do with the help of reverse iterators

```
#include <algorithm> //  std::copy
#include <iterator>  

friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Board const& board) /* noexcept */
//                                              ^^^^^^^--> also pass the object by const-ref
{
   std::copy(board.m_Board_board.crbegin(), board.m_Board_board.crend(),
      std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, "\n"));
   return os;
}
```

Here is [a working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jqv1b9).

Comment: Ooh yea! Thanks a lot! But when I am using constant iterator like so ```iter = board.end()-1; iter != board.begin()-1; ++iter``` It still shows me the same error although this time I am making sure to not go out of bounds here

Comment: What is no except keyword?

Comment: ```vector<int>::const_iterator iter;
  for (iter = board.m_Board_board.end() - 1; iter >= board.m_Board_board.begin(); --iter) {
   os << *iter;
  }
  return os;```